# JSON response ignoring tags declared in PHP file

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(1);

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {

$tag = $_POST['tag'];

require_once 'DB_Functions.php';

$response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

// check for tag type
if ($tag == 'username') {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    if(isset($username) && !empty($username)){
        $response = isUserRegistered($username);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}

} else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

This is my main.php file that returns some JSON data from my DB after calling a function based on tag in the file. This seem to work fine on my local server however, after uploading it on live server, this is always returning {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameter 'tag' is missing!"}

I tried passing the tag parameter for the request, but it is just going to the else part of the php file.

can someone pls advise on what I might be missing

thanks in advance

Comment: check if you're getting a value in `$_POST['tag']`

Comment: try `$_REQUEST['tag']` instead of `$_POST['tag']`

Comment: @madforstrength I tried your suggestion, still same result.

Comment: @Criesto - Not sure how I am supposed to check that

Comment: @BountyHunter before `if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {` do a `echo $_POST['tag']; die;`.

Comment: @Criesto it gives me no data. "Response does not contain any data."

Comment: @BountyHunter, that is why you're getting the error `{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameter 'tag' is missing!"}` as the first if condition fails. Check your code why aren't you getting any value in `if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {`

Comment: I am using Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 ,  PHP/5.4.44. Is there some setting I need to enable for the request url to accept parameters?

Comment: @BountyHunter No. Its obvious that you're not getting any value in `$_POST['tag']`. You'll have to post more code so that I can see where from this page is being accessed. This might also be the right time for you to start learning the basics of php. :)